using Type expression in switch label
Code
Type fieldType = typeof(string);
switch(fieldType) {
    case typeof(string):
      break;
   }

Throws compile error

CS9135    A constant value of type 'Type' is expected Eeva

at line
  case typeof(string):

How to use Type constants in switch labels?
Using .NET 8 and Visual Studio 17.11.5
